# Keycloak Step Up from Client

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect, keycloak-nodejs-connect

The Keycloak [documentation here](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_step-up-flow) says you need to add ACR with claims in the request in order to do authentication step up to a higher level. But how is this accomplished from either the keycloak.js client library, or the keycloak-js npm client library?

So basically, how do you get the following claims query param to be passed?

```
https://{DOMAIN}/realms/{REALMNAME}/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id={CLIENT-ID}&redirect_uri={REDIRECT-URI}&scope=openid&response_type=code&response_mode=query&nonce=exg16fxdjcu&claims=%7B%22id_token%22%3A%7B%22acr%22%3A%7B%22essential%22%3Atrue%2C%22values%22%3A%5B%22gold%22%5D%7D%7D%7D
```

The format of the claims is like this as seen in the documentation:

```
claims= {
        "id_token": {
            "acr": {
                "essential": true,
                "values": ["gold"]
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing this off the top of my head, but I think this should do it.

```
const keycloak = Keycloak({
  url: {DOMAIN},
  realm: {REALMNAME},
  clientId: {CLIENT-ID}
});

keycloak.login({
    ... your login options
    acr: { values: ["silver", "gold"], essential: true } 
})
```

The adapter will take the `acr` option and apply it to `claims.id_token`